# Given a characteristic polynomial, how to find the characteristic polynomial multiplied by scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix over the reals, and $c\in\mathbb{R}^*.$ Given $B:=c A $ and $P_A(t)$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$, where
$$p_A(t) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i t^i$$
how does one express $P_B(t)$ as function of $P_A(t)$?

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$p_{cA}(t) = \det(cA - tI) = c^n\det\left(A- \frac{t}{c}I\right) = c^n p_A\left(\frac{t}c\right)$$

Comment: I think it would be better to emphasize that this assumes $c \neq 0$, and then treat the case $c=0$ separately.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yeah, of course. If $c = 0$ then $cA = 0$ so $$p_{cA}(t) = p_0(t) = \det(-\lambda I) = (-\lambda)^n$$